# How to detect touches on MPMoviePlayerController window and still having the standard playback controlling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I have the MPMoviePlayerController set up to play a movie.I want to detect a touch on the movie for bringing up few buttons.I used the code :

```
 // The movie's window is the one that is active
        UIWindow* moviePlayerWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
        // Now we create an invisible control with the same size as the window
        UIControl* overlay = [[[UIControl alloc] initWithFrame:moviePlayerWindow.frame]autorelease];
```

```
    // We want to get notified whenever the overlay control is touched
    [overlay addTarget:self action:@selector(movieWindowTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    // Add the overlay to the window's subviews
    [moviePlayerWindow addSubview:overlay];
```

but then the play back controllers doesn't appear , I guess because the player window doesn't get the touch.how can I keep the player controllers and still detects touches?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your own UIView's subclass and add it as overlay.

In the method `-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` you can do everything you want to do when the screen is touched.

I have done this in my project. I have implemented design of the VideoOverlay( the UIView's subclass) in Interface Builder. It is much easier when you have to add other elements that user have to interact with.

Comment: Thanks , but how do I pass the touch event to the MPMoviePlayerController in order to have his native controllers?

Comment: [[self nextResponder]touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

Comment: Doesn't work for me, on iPad 3.2.1. It seems whatever I do, I cannot have both my overlay and the player responding :(

Comment: Call super: [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event]